# Unable to open sound device: Invalid or unsupported audio device operation

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

Cannot figure out why CSipSimple works correctly on my android phone but when I try my own code using the same CSipSimple Library on call_make_call(..) my app crashes in this way:
Cannot figure out what's happening. I'm handling all the callbacks but only the ON_REG_STATE is fired. Someone had the same problem ?

```
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.930 android_jni_de  Default params
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.931 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.931  pjsua_media.c  Opening sound device PCM@16000/1/20ms
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.931 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.931 android_jni_de  Creating stream
I/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.931 android_jni_de  Create stream : 16000 samples/sec, 320     samples/frame, 2 bytes/sample
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.931 android_jni_de  Default params
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.932 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.932  pjsua_media.c  Opening sound device PCM@44100/1/20ms
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.932 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.932 android_jni_de  Creating stream
I/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.932 android_jni_de  Create stream : 44100 samples/sec, 882     samples/frame, 2 bytes/sample
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.933 android_jni_de  Default params
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.933 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.933  pjsua_media.c  Opening sound device PCM@48000/1/20ms
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934 android_jni_de  Creating stream
I/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934 android_jni_de  Create stream : 48000 samples/sec, 960 samples/frame, 2 bytes/sample
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934 android_jni_de  Default params
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934  pjsua_media.c  Opening sound device PCM@32000/1/20ms
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.934 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.935 android_jni_de  Creating stream
I/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.935 android_jni_de  Create stream : 32000 samples/sec, 640 samples/frame, 2 bytes/sample
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.935 android_jni_de  Default params
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.935 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.935  pjsua_media.c  Opening sound device PCM@16000/1/20ms
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.935 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.936 android_jni_de  Creating stream
I/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.936 android_jni_de  Create stream : 16000 samples/sec, 320 samples/frame, 2 bytes/sample
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.936 android_jni_de  Default params
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.936 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.936  pjsua_media.c  Opening sound device PCM@8000/1/20ms
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.936 android_jni_de  Get dev info
D/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.937 android_jni_de  Creating stream
I/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.937 android_jni_de  Create stream : 8000 samples/sec, 160 samples/frame, 2 bytes/sample
E/libpjsip(21325):  16:24:19.937  pjsua_media.c  Unable to open sound device: Invalid     or unsupported audio device operation (PJMEDIA_EAUD_INVOP) [status=420009]
```

Comment: i have same issue, do u find solution?

Comment: did you check and make it sure, the audio codec of both sides are same ?